# Passing parameters to custom devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to specify a custom 'from' email when sending out devise emails.

So far I have created a customer mailer, and am overwriting part of the default methods, but I have no clue on how to pass in arguments, like current_user

Example:

```
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    Rails.logger.debug 'Sending custom confirmation instructions...'
    customer_responsible = current_user.company
    info_email           = customer_responsible.info_email
    opts[:from]          = info_email if info_email
    super
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.debug e.inspect
    throw e
  end

end
```